# C# Keeping dropdown menu open when Dragon NaturallySpeaking's MouseGrid opens

Tags: c#, menu, grid, dropdown, naturallyspeaking

How can I keep a dropdown menu open when Dragon NaturallySpeaking's MouseGrid opens? I'm using C# and Windows 10. The MouseGrid overlays the desktop screen with the grid that allows the user to quickly jump to numbered quadrants. Some applications will keep the dropdown open when the overlay opens, but it seems that the C# applications created by Visual Studio close the menu as soon as the grid appears.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet in that case is to not navigate with the Mouse Grid.  What happens if you just say the choice, or start pressing arrow keys (say "press down arrow") or hitting the tab key to get to it?

You can try using mouse motion commands ("move mouse left") but the dropdown may also disappear.  Or best to use an advanced scripting command to just click the spot you want.  You don't say what version of Dragon you use so you might not have scripting ability.  If that's the case, you can use Dragon to call an external script to do it (just put a shortcut on the desktop).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the mouse motion command usually work fine(there are times when the mouse doesn't move at all, but that happens in many applications). Pressing arrow keys doesn't work (nothing happens) so I was hoping that there was some setting that would keep the menu open until either an item is selected or the escape key is pressed.

Comment: How do you activate the dropdown menu? If you do it by voice and using the mouse to get there and click (e.g., mousegrid or mouse movement commands), then presumably the cursor is rather nearby the dropped list.  In that case, you can use the "mouse <direction> <num 1-10> [and optionally <mouseaction>]" command to move the cursor in specific intervals.  Note, it is also possible to modify (or copy as new) that command to make the <num> list go greater than 10 pixels at a time (but again, you don't say what version of Dragon you use - do you have scripting capabilities?)

Comment: Moving the Mouse (can also move and click): https://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/enx/professionalgroup/main/Content/CommandandControl/using_your_mouse.htm#MoveMousePointer or Scripting a Mouse movement or click: https://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/scriptref/Content/scrptref/setmouseposition.htm

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I haven't tried scripting before, but I give it a try!